# Ruby on Rails - redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having some trouble understanding the redirect_to statement.
I have a model "Book" (with an boolean attribute "read")and a controller "books". Now I created a second controller "Admins" having to methods: index and change.
The index view just renders a list off all Books with a link to the change method:

```
<% @Books.each do |d| %>
<%= d.title %><br>
<% if d.read==true %>
<%= link_to "mark unread", change_path(:id=>d.id)%>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "mark read", change_path(:id=>d.id)%>
<%end %>
```

Now the change method just changes the "read" attribute:

```
@book=Book.find(params[:id])
if @book.read==true
@book.update_attributes(:read => false)
else
@book.update_attributes(:read => true)
end
redirect_to action: "index"
```

The Problem is: rails tries to redirect me to the show action using the :id as a parameter...(perhaps because the change_url is /admins/change?id=3)
But I just want to be directed back to the index view "/admins"

is there a way? it seems like rails always tries to redirect to the view action if there is an id as a parameter

Thanks alot

PS: the routes.rb contains resources:admins and resources:books

Comment: How do you know that `rails tries to redirect me to the show action using the :id as a parameter`? Do you get any error? If yes, please share the server log generated for the same.

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
redirect_to :controller => 'admins', :action => 'index'
```

Or

```
redirect_to admins_url
```

The above two will direct you to the `index` page of `AdminsController`. There is no way that Rails would route it to `show` action UNLESS you are redirecting to `show` action from the `index` action of `AdminsController`. Since, you did not share `index` action code of `AdminsController`, I would recommend you to check there.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a clear explanation of redirect_to ... checkout

https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1210155

Comment: The article is great. This article explains very clear why do `render` and `redirect_to` are needed and what is their difference. Example about refreshing and duplicating is valuable.  Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I had a kind of similar issue some days ago. I would suggest to do this within the form where you list the books and the mark/unmark checkboxes.

```
<%= form_for @book,:url => book_index_path do |f| %>
```

This worked fine for me, when I set up a site where you create data and the user is immediately redirected to the same page (incl. success/error message).. to do a kind of
human batch-processing.